# How many Graphs with 5 vertices (a, b, c, d, e) have only one vertex with rank 4?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Having trouble with the following combinatorics/graphes problem:

How many Graphs with 5 vertices (a, b, c, d, e) have only one vertex with degree 4?

I'm thinking about writing down all the possibilities, calculate the possibility of each case and sum all results. But is that the only solution?

Comment: Are these simple graphs? [undirected, no loops, no parallel edges] Also for completeness of the question what is the rank of a vertex? Is that the same as the degree of the vertex? Finally are you looking for number of isomorphism types, or number of labelled graphs>

Comment: It's a general graph. no further  assumptions.

Comment: If no further assumptions then no definite answer exists. I'm fairly sure that for simple graphs there are up to isomorphism 11 such graphs. The unique vertex of degree 4 must have the other 4 vertices at the other ends of the edges from it, and then these remaining 4 unused vertices may be made into a simple graph in 11 nonisomorphic ways.

Comment: LioH-- Did you get an answer? If it's for simple graphs, I could give details for getting 11 nonisomorphic (as suggested in previous comment).

Comment: Hey, I only have the question. And it only says "Graph G". it might be a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If we delete the degree-4 vertex, we obtain a 4-vertex graph with maximum degree at most 2.  We can count them (up to isomorphism) by hand:

[image]

(I generated the above using `geng` which comes with Nauty.  The vertices are marked with their degrees.)

After deleting the unique degree-4 vertex, the graphs are:

- $4K_1$
- $2K_1 \cup K_2$
- $K_1 \cup P_2$ (where $P_2$ is a 2-edge path)
- $2K_2$
- $P_3$
- $K_1 \cup K_3$
- $C_4$

If we instead want the number of labeled graphs, we can sum $5!/|\mathrm{aut}(G)|$ for each graph $G$, via the [Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_theorem).  This gives
\begin{align*}
& \frac{5!}{4!}
+\frac{5!}{4}
+\frac{5!}{2}
+\frac{5!}{8}
+\frac{5!}{2}
+\frac{5!}{3!}
+\frac{5!}{8} \\
= {} & 5+30+60+15+60+20+15 \\
= {} & 205.
\end{align*}